# So what if Fire Lord Sozin was able to kill Aang?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

After the death of Avatar Roku, the Fire Nation attacked and killed all the Air Nomads in hopes of killing the reincarnation of the Avatar.  But so what if they did kill the Air Nomad Avatar, wouldn't he just get reincarnated into the Water Tribes right away?  What was the Fire Nations' plan exactly, to go around the four nations and keep killing the reincarnation of the Avatar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not? Every time the Fire Nation kills a 10-year-old Avatar, they gain another decade. Maybe capturing Aang and making him live a long and useless life would be better, but it'd also be a lot harder.

Sozin may also think — rightly or not — that he can break the Avatar cycle by killing all the Air Nomads, in which case there'll only be three more Avatars to worry about after Aang...

Comment: which makes one wonder if air bending would ever naturally reoccur somehow (since we now know there are still sky bison around).

Comment: It would be easier and far more sensible to subdue the Avatar if he were young and keep him fed and imprisoned somewhere. If he has not been trained to open all four of his bending techniques, he will never be a threat, will never get his energy bending powers and will live out his life, giving them much more time than if they hunted down the Avatar each time he/she appeared.

Comment: @Thaddeus: I see two problems with that from Sozin's standpoint. First, he doesn't know who the Avatar is. Holding one captive boy may be easy; holding all the Air Nomad children of the right age captive is a lot harder. Second, the existence of the Avatar State means no Avatar, even an entirely untrained one, makes a particularly safe captive. Perhaps Sozin's true best option is to suborn the Avatar, but given that he's already failed spectacularly at that I don't find it too surprising that he thinks repeatedly killing Avatars is the next best solution.

Comment: Sozin thought too highly of his own ability and not highly enough of the Avatar. Pride ever goeth before a fall.

Comment: But doesn't that mean that once it is time for the Fire Nation Avatar, the Fire Nation would have to go around and kill Fire Nation babies... Wouldn't that be bad PR to start killing babies from your own nation?

Comment: @Arm0geddon: He doesn't have to do exactly the same thing to every Avatar that pops up. It wouldn't surprise me if his response to a Fire Nation Avatar was either much-more-selective murder or another Roku-like attempt to get him/her on his side (this time starting from a much earlier age!)

Comment: @KutuluMike: Wow, your 6 year old comment aged incredibly well. Thanks spirit world!

Answer (score 1):

If the fire lord had killed Aang in the avatar state then the line of avatars would cease to exist.

Comment: Welcome to this website! Could you include a bit more informations and sources, to complete this single affirmation?